# Visual Studio Code on macOS + Qt + Intellisense

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, cmake

Visual Studio Code gets the following error:

```
cannot open source file "QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h" (dependency of "QApplication")C/C++(1696)
```

I have a CMake project which compiled and built successfully, but it seems that Intellisense doesn't work.

I have this directory in a path which contains `qtwidgetsglobal.h`:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers
```

And there is another thing:

Directory `/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework`
contains directory `Headers` and strange executable `QtWidgets` I was assumed to include `-I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework` because QtCreator has both
`/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework` and
`/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers`
but nothing worked.

Actually Visual Studio Code seems to ignore if both directories
`/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework` and
`/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers`
specified.

Any suggestions how to enable Intellisense to work with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: have you read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Comment: yes, all needed includes should be taken from compiler-commands.json. My another deps works fine except Qt.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the compileCommands instead of the cake-tools configurationProvider.

Therefore in your `c_cpp_properties.json` add the line

```
"compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json",
```

and remove

```
"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
```

---

The full config file should look something like this

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json",
            "browse": {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            },
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "cppStandard": "c++14"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not use VSCode for compilation, so I do not have a build folder,
and the above advice did not work for me.

I was able to make Intellisense work with QT after adding a Qt folder with frameworks into the macFrameworkPath section of the c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
"macFrameworkPath": [
    "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks",
    "~/Qt/6.3.1/macos/lib/**"
```

],

P.S. Before come to this simple solution, I have read and try advice to add file associations to force extensionless QT headers, e.g.   to be CPP type files. People told this worked for them, but for me not.

```
"files.associations": {
        "*.": "cpp"
},
```